# Tcl) Auto-unset of 'varlist' while using 'foreach'

Tags: foreach, namespaces, tcl

While running the following:

```
foreach Var {Item1 Item2 Item3} {
    # Do something
}
```

The variable 'Var' have the value of 'Item3'. Is there an option to auto-unset it or I'll have the unset it manually?

The reason for asking is that I define multiple namespaces by using 'foreach' statement and it leaves me a lot of un-needed variables around.

Specifically, I need to define some variables in a namespace:

```
namespace eval ::Bla {
    foreach Var {Item1 Item2 Item3} {variable $Var}
}
```

Is there a way to re-write the code which does not leave the 'Var' set rather than unset it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of variables is either the procedure(-like thing, so this also includes lambdas and methods) or the namespace (and the global scope is just a namespace). The `foreach` command does nothing at all with defining scopes; Tcl has *never* worked that way, and I wouldn't expect it to change any time soon. If you want one of the iteration variables removed (`foreach` can have multiple such variables) then you'll have to `unset` it yourself.

```
foreach Var {Item1 Item2 Item3} {
    # Do something
}
unset Var
```

I advise always using `foreach` inside a procedure (lambda, method) if you're doing anything complicated. It goes faster.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific problem, you could put the namespace initialization code into a `proc` so it goes away when the proc ends.

```
proc createNamespaceVars {ns args} {
     namespace eval $ns {
         foreach Var $args {variable $Var}
     }
}
```

But there is no magic unset switch as already explained by Donal.